# How to specify openmpi in find_package(MPI required)

Tags: cmake, mpi, openmpi

How can I specifically make cmake to search for openmpi libraries only? I would like cmake to throw error if openmpi is missing and even if mpich is installed.

Comment: Look at this flag MPI_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX . Source : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindMPI.html